Login Button for microsoft authentication is giving undefined, (reading 'endsWith')
I have a React with .net application and i'm authenticating users through microsoft entra id, without an identity provider.
On localhost it signs in the user and it authorizes the API, but when deployed (separately, one app service for each) i get this error before giving me the login popup, so it doesnt open anything:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'endsWith')
    at w.transformCIAMAuthority (Authority.ts:1295:52)
    at le (AuthorityFactory.ts:43:41)
    at FunctionWrappers.ts:102:16
    at Je.getDiscoveredAuthority (BaseInteractionClient.ts:213:43)
    at FunctionWrappers.ts:102:16
    at Je.getClientConfiguration (StandardInteractionClient.ts:250:43)
    at FunctionWrappers.ts:102:16
    at Je.createAuthCodeClient (StandardInteractionClient.ts:216:36)
    at FunctionWrappers.ts:102:16
    at Je.acquireToken (RedirectClient.ts:131:63)

For now my app is simple, a login button on the main page where i have another components that call an api.
This is the login button:
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useMsal } from "@azure/msal-react";
import { useAuth } from "../../context/AuthTokenContext";

const LoginButton = () => {
  const { instance } = useMsal();
  const { setToken } = useAuth();

  useEffect(() => {
    instance
      .handleRedirectPromise()
      .then((response) => {
        if (response && response.accessToken) {
          console.log("Successful token acquisition via redirect:", response);
          setToken(response.accessToken);
        }
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.error("Error handling redirect:", e);
      });
  }, [instance, setToken]);

  const handleLogin = () => {
    instance
      .loginRedirect({
        scopes: [process.env.REACT_APP_SCOPE || ""],
        redirectUri: process.env.REACT_APP_REDIRECT_URI,
        authority: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTHORITY,
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.error(e);
      });
  };

  return <button onClick={handleLogin}>Sign In</button>;
};

export default LoginButton;`
This is the authConfig:
/*
 * Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
 * Licensed under the MIT License.
 */

import { LogLevel } from "@azure/msal-browser";

/**
 * Configuration object to be passed to MSAL instance on creation.
 * For a full list of MSAL.js configuration parameters, visit:
 * https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/configuration.md
 */
export const msalConfig = {
  auth: {
    clientId: process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID || "",
    authority: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTHORITY || "",
    redirectUri: process.env.REACT_APP_REDIRECT_URI || "",
    audience: process.env.REACT_APP_AUDIENCE || "",
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: "localStorage", // This configures where your cache will be stored
    storeAuthStateInCookie: true, // Set this to "true" if you are having issues on IE11 or Edge
  },
  system: {
    loggerOptions: {
      loggerCallback: (level: any, message: any, containsPii: any) => {
        if (containsPii) {
          return;
        }
        switch (level) {
          case LogLevel.Error:
            console.error(message);
            return;
          case LogLevel.Info:
            console.info(message);
            return;
          case LogLevel.Verbose:
            console.debug(message);
            return;
          case LogLevel.Warning:
            console.warn(message);
            return;
          default:
            return;
        }
      },
    },
  },
};

/**
 * Scopes you add here will be prompted for user consent during sign-in.
 * By default, MSAL.js will add OIDC scopes (openid, profile, email) to any login request.
 * For more information about OIDC scopes, visit:
 * https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#openid-connect-scopes
 */
export const loginRequest = {
  scopes: [process.env.REACT_APP_SCOPE || ""],
};

/**
 * Add here the scopes to request when obtaining an access token for MS Graph API. For more information, see:
 * https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/resources-and-scopes.md
 */
export const graphConfig = {
  graphMeEndpoint: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me", //e.g. https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
};

This is the auth context:
import React, {
  createContext,
  useContext,
  useState,
  useEffect,
  ReactNode,
} from "react";
import { useMsal, useIsAuthenticated } from "@azure/msal-react";

interface AuthContextType {
  token: string | null;
  setToken: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string | null>>;
}

const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextType | undefined>(undefined);

export const AuthProvider: React.FC<{ children: ReactNode }> = ({
  children,
}) => {
  const [token, setToken] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const { instance, accounts } = useMsal();
  const isAuthenticated = useIsAuthenticated();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuthenticated && accounts.length > 0) {
      const getToken = async () => {
        try {
          const silentToken = await instance.acquireTokenSilent({
            scopes: [process.env.REACT_APP_SCOPE || ""],
            account: accounts[0],
          });
          setToken(silentToken.accessToken);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error acquiring token silently", error);
          setToken(null);
        }
      };
      getToken();
    }
  }, [instance, accounts, isAuthenticated]);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ token, setToken }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useAuth = () => {
  const context = useContext(AuthContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error("useAuth must be used within a AuthProvider");
  }
  return context;
};

On backend i have only this line for authentication:
builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(builder.Configuration); 
And the controller looks like this:
[ApiController]
[Route("api")]
[Authorize(Roles = "User")]
public class IncidentController : Controller
{
    private readonly IIncidentService _incidentService;

    public IncidentController(IIncidentService incidentService)
    {
        _incidentService = incidentService;
    }

I have set only two redirect uris, /

the hosted on azure web app
the localhost

Also i have enabled this settings:

I have tried changing all the environment variables, changing the backend middleware for authentication, changing the redirect uris, enabling and disabling settings, nothing works and there are no similar problems to find solutions.
My variables for front end looks something like:
REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID="fe-clientid"
REACT_APP_AUTHORITY=https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid
REACT_APP_REDIRECT_URI="webappUrl"
REACT_APP_SCOPE=api://"backendclientId"/access_as_user
REACT_APP_AUDIENCE=api://"backendclientId"

For backend are named like:


Are you mapping AzureAd:Authority to REACT_APP_AUTHORITY somewhere in your code? Because it appears to me you should be using the value with process.env["AzureAd:Authority"], not process.env.REACT_APP_AUTHORITY. Same applies to the other env variables.

@NerdyStudent If Possible, Share your repository here?

@NerdyStudent Did you change the redirect url localhost to Azure web app url After deploying?

AzureAd:Authority is mapped in .net by the middleware. I have fixed this issue, the problem as it shows, was because i was setting react variables in azure app service, but i should have set them in the build pipeline, strange behavior but at least it works.
